# Why would Gearman return empty http response

Tags: gearman

I have configured Gearman to accept request via http too.

I have a terminal with a running worker in which I confirm that workload is passed, and I receive a 200 status with expected headers, but Content-Length 0 and, of course, empty response body.

Any ideea why?

.. other than "The HTTP protocol should be considered experimental." :)

Comment: How did you configure `gearman` to accept request via http? In which language gearman client and workers are written?

Comment: Hussain, as I said, gearman is configured to accept http requests (I receive an expected response - at least in what concerns headers, and I see live what worker - written in PHP - receives as workload). The only problem is that response does not contain body load, though X-Gearman-Command header value is "WORK_COMPLETE" and the request is not for a background execution (which would indeed send an empty response body)

Comment: Don't know about that. Can't help you there. really sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your intent, much apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/http/protocol.cc implementation.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand/+bug/1152707